# Stub Active Record count with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, stubs

I'm struggling to figure out how to stub the following:

```
def max_post_limit
    Post.on(date).count > some_limit
end
```

I'm trying to stub the Post... section, not the method. 
So far I have tried the following and similar variations. All return either 0 or 1.

```
before do 
    Post.stubs(:on).returns([])
    Post.stubs.(:on).with(date).returns([])
    Post.stubs.(:count).returns(some_limit)
end
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: letz's solution should work, but when you need to stub a chain of calls, it's often a sign that the interface between the classes could be improved. In this case, you could extract a method `Post.count_on_date(date)` which is then very easy to stub.

Comment: The test suite is using mocha so i was going down the wrong path, apologies.

I took your advice and created a `Post.created_on(date)` method and am now trying:

   post = Post.new
   post.expects(:created_on).with(date).returns(123)

However, the error is 0 arguments for 1. 
Any advice on correctly passing the date variable? I thought `with` was doing that. Apparently not?

Comment: `created_on` is a class method, but it looks like you're stubbing an instance. I'm not sure of the mocha syntax, in RSpec it would be `allow(Post).to receive(:created_on).with(...).and_return(...)`

Answer (score 0):

try:

`allow(Post).to receive_message_chain(:on, :count) { 123 }`